# Multiplication Field in Java / SceneBuilder

Tags: java, eclipse, multiplication, scenebuilder, calculation

I'm a java Beginner and I've created a program where you can type in some food in a TableView and the details of the respective food you can type in a GripPane. One of the Details you have to type in is the quantity of the food, and another is the Calories per piece. Now I would like to create a button and a field. Or Maybe just a field that shows all calories of the food in the Table view. So it should multiplicate the quantity with the calories, for every food and add them all together. For a Total of Calories. Now I have no idea how to do that. Could somebody help me with step-by-step instructions? Not sure if it makes sense to add some code to the program. By the way, I use Eclipse on Windows and SceneBuilder. Thanks for every help.
Cheers Blarg

Comment: Please add code, and please narrow down your question to one specific issue. Are you struggling with the button? Are you struggling to get text from the textBox? Are you struggling to convert the text to a number? The basic steps are to first get the text `String text = yourTextbox.getText();`, then convert it to a number `int count = Integer.parseInt(text);` then once you have both the count and the calories you can make a simple calculation `Double totalCalories  = count * calories;`.

Answer (score 1):

The first piece of advice from my side would be to try writing some code on your own! That way you learn and you wouldn't need to copy and paste somebody else's code.

And secondly, this is how I would approach it:

1. Create the fields as you described below in the Scene Builder and give them all id (names) so that we can access them in our controller (I am supposing you know how that works).
2. Add a button so that the user can click to perform the calculation
3. When the button is clicked, you can get all the information from each `TextBox` and create a `Food` Object with all the information. Performing the calculation is a rather simple task that can be done by converting the data received from the `TextBox`es into numbers and multiplying

```
public void addFoodItemIntoTable()
{
    ...
    String quantityOfFoodStr = quantityTextBox.getText();
    int quantityOfFood = Integer.parseInt(quantityOfFoodStr);
    
    String caloriesOfFoodStr = caloriesTextBox.getText();
    double caloriesOfFood = Double.parseDouble(caloriesOfFoodStr);
    
    double total = quantityOfFood * caloriesOfFood;
    
    ...
}
```

4. After adding all the elements in your `TableView` [(Check this)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366828/add-a-simple-row-to-javafx-tableview). You can easily get the total of the field by iterating all the elements of your table and adding them into a variable.

Example:

```java
double total = 0;
for(Food currentFood : foodTable.getItems())
{
    total = total + currentFood.getTotalCalculation(); // The naming should not be correct... Change it to whatever you find suitable
}
```

Good luck!